# flake8 not honoring global configuration. elpy

Tags: python, emacs, emacs24, flake8, elpy

I am new to emacs & trying to use it for python programming. I have installed elpy & everything is working fine except one thing - I am getting lot of warnings, errors like E401, E402, E501 etc. All are in scary red colors.

After researching little bit, it looks like these errors are coming from flake8. So I configure flake8 as follows:

In ~/.config/flake8,

```
[flake8]
ignore=E201,E203,E211,E221,E272,E251,E211,E222,E226,E228,E241,E301,E302,E401,E402,E501,E701,F401
max-line-length=160
exclude=tests/*
max-complexity=10
```

But still those errors are coming. I also configured same way PEP8 & pycodestyle in `.config/`. But no progress. I tried to put `setup.cfg` & `tox.ini` in project root, but that also didn't work.

For more information, there is similar ticket in sublime flake8 repo. 
https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-flake8/issues/24

Please let me know if there is any working solution or emacs hacks.

Following are some details

```
Os - Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
flake8 version - 3.0.0b1 (pyflakes: 1.2.3, pycodestyle: 2.0.0, mccabe: 0.5.0)
GNU Emacs 24.3.1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try running flake8 directly against the code that you're writing? If you do and have the same problem, can you share the output of `flake8 -v`

Comment: This seems to be broken for me as well. If I have my configuration file in ~/.flake8, and I have my .py files in some subdirectory of ~/, then it picks up the file.  This is not expected since I want a *global* location for this setup,  and not have to copy the flake8 configuration settings across all projects I use.

Answer (score 13):

Anyone trying to get this running for `flake8>=4.0.0`, that's because support for global config file is no longer present, see https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/release-notes/4.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes.

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting emacs. For me it picks up ~/.config/flake8 when emacs is started, but doesn't pick it up between runs.